# Удаление сессии

Tags: php

ЛОР следующий:

1 - имеем юзера, который сейчас сидит на сайте, использует его (листает, лайкает, в общем, проявляет активность)

2 - Администратор удаляет его профиль через базу данных. Но сессия юзера то никуда не делась..

Вопрос - как корректно удалить сессию этого пользователя ? Они вроде как хранятся у сервера, но как понять, какая сессия принадлежит конкретному пользователю ? Буду рад любой статье для прочтения. Спасибо!

Comment: А через что храните сессии? PHPSESSID?

Comment: @Андрей Да, по стандарту

Answer (score 1):

Ну, в скрипт авторизации можно добавить проверку профиля по базе и соответственно удалять сессию если юзер заблокирован.

Answer (score 0):

Хранить связь между [session_id()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-id.php) и пользователем, и [закрывать сессию](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443355/remotely-destroy-a-session-in-php-user-logs-in-somewhere-else) по этому идентификатору когда пользователь удаляется. Опять же, при запросе к примеру в Laravel запрос проходит через прокладку, где можно определить, есть ли пользователь у сессии или нет, так что зависит ещё и от используемого framework’а.

Comment: фреймворка нет. Самопис )

Comment: Значит в коде удаления пользователя закрывайте его сессию вручную с помощью примера по ссылке.

Comment: Да, прочитал..как я понял, это не совсем то, что нужно. Там суть заключается в повторной авторизации. А если таковой нет ? Юзер просто обновляет страницу и видит пустое место, вместо аватара и т.п.. Или я не правильно понял ?

Comment: Так пишите подробно моменты и сценарии, а то вот такие комментарии отбивают желание давать ответы, которые само собой будут неполными. Я поэтому и писал про прокладку потому что в ней есть возможность проверить пользователя по сессии и сделать редирект на страницу авторизации/логина.

Comment: Так я вроде все понятно описал. Нужно удалить сессию. Удалить, а не просить юзера заново авторизоваться, после того, как его стерли с базы данных. Моя проблема, как я понял, относится к куки т.к PHPSESSID хранит инфу о сессии. Следовательно, когда я её затираю, то все работает как надо. Но за помощь - спасибо.

Comment: Конкретно по вашему вопросу я ответ дал - с привязкой и удалением session_id() у пользователя. Вопрос корректности - субъективный, так как нет описания той самой "корректности" в том, как вы её себе представляете. Меньше субъективности, больше конкретики, и в итоге выйдет что правильная постановка вопроса - уже половина ответа.